# Stopping Adobe Reader XI zooming when following links

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-reader, zoom

I regularly read long PDF's and the best way for me to read these PDF's is showing a single page and setting the `Page Display` to `Single Page View`.  This allows me to use the mouse wheel to quickly scroll from page to page.  On my laptop this means that the document zoom is about 60%.

However these PDFs have embedded links that allow me to jump from the current page to the linked location anywhere else in the PDF.  But when I follow such a link Adobe Reader bumps the zoom up to 350% so that the target of the link is prominently centered in the screen.

As such I need to manually re-zoom the document to fit the entire screen again.  And my documents have a *lot* of links in them that I am continually following.  So this behavior annoys the %&^%$ out of me.

Is there anyway to disable this automatic zooming of the document when following links?

---

Testing other viewers

1. Preview in OSX doesn't exhibit the zooming behavior (but that
   doesn't help me)

Comment: Have you tried any of the alternative readers, such as Sumatra and PDF-XChange Viewer?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No, but this is a corporate load.  However I will try them out

Comment: Oops... you're right. You can test at home, and then have IT decide if the application is acceptable.